# Has anyone been able to get a iMac iSight camera to work in Google Meet inside Chromium?

Tags: chromium, mac, webcam, google-hangouts

Just took an old Late 2006 iMac, maxed out the hardware upgrades, and installed Ubuntu 20.04 to be my kids' new remote learning computer. Found so much help on this site. Thanks!

Basically everything is working perfectly now EXCEPT the built-in iSight camera for Google Meet (school requirement), but only when running in Chromium.  The video camera works fine in Cheese, Zoom, and even **ironically works in Firefox running Google Meet**.

I have entirely turned off the "prompt for camera access" setting in Chromium... can't find any other kind of access or privacy restrictions related to cameras.

This is a pretty minor issue because we can just use Firefox for that one app, but it kind of irks me. I'm curious if anyone else has run into this and managed to get around it. This iMac has the older iSight camera, rather than the FaceTimeHD that's in the newer models.

Comment: Is chromium a snap install perhaps? and firefox not a snap install? That is one thing I can imagine that could be the issue.

Comment: both Chromium and Firefox were installed via the Ubuntu Software app... I looked at the About page for that app and it shows Snap Support as installed and enabled.

Comment: interesting, got to looking around the Ubuntu Software app and didn't realize each app has a Permissions button that allows you to set stuff like camera access for the app. Camera access is indeed enabled for Chromium though.  Also tried enabling direct USB access, since I think the camera probably has an internal usb connection.

Comment: ah probably found it.

Comment: hahahahahaaaaa... just moments ago got a notice from the school district that so many people are having problems with Google Meet that they've bought a Zoom license for the year.  Zoom works fine with this camera and Ubuntu.

Comment: ok :) make sure it is zoom 5, the  version before it are seriously flawed

Comment: ugh, installed zoom 5.2, the latest... basically works fine, but the video pane has all these tiny red speckles going on.  looks fine on the other side.  next problem for me to solve...

Answer (score 1):

Do this from command line

```
sudo snap connect chromium:camera :camera
```

and comment if that worked for you ;)

[Found it on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741253).

Comment: i appreciate the answer, but it didn't seem to have any effect. i did a full shutdown and power off reboot too.